# How to show AJAX response on new page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing mobile app in phonegap and using intel xdk and i want to show ajax response on new html page I have searched on google and found this solution  `window.open();`  but this method does not work for me and show blank (white screen). I want to show the data in my `search.html` page and I'm using jquery and ajax for getting response from database.

```
function search() {
    $("#LoadingImage").show();
    var valuee=document.querySelector('input[name="srch_type"]:checked').value;
    var srch_txt = $("#search-2").val();
    if(srch_txt.length>0){
       $.ajax({
              url: "http://medicomall.com/andapp/?srchtxt="+srch_txt+"&srchtyp="+valuee,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(opt) {
                 $("#LoadingImage").hide();                                          
                 $.each(opt.waleed, function(key, value){   
                       //  alert( "SUCCESS:  " + value );         
                       if(valuee=='Medicine'){                   
                            $("ul").html ("<li>"+this['med_name']+"</li>"+"<li>"+this['med_alter']+"</li><a>"+this['Store_Address']+"</a><br>");
                       }else if(valuee=='Doctor'){        
                            $("ul").html("<li>"+this['name']+"</li><li>"+this['desc']+"</li>");
                      }  
                 else{
                     $("ul").html("<li>"+this['cl_name']+"</li><li>"+this['cl_address']+"</li>");   
                 }
            });  
          },
           error: function () {
               alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
               $("#LoadingImage").hide();

            }     

        });   
   } else{
            alert("Please Enter Some Value");
            $("#LoadingImage").hide();     
         }
     }

  </script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to put it in another page ? A popup with an overlay should work. If you really want it in another page. Why not calling the window.open with the search in the query string (srchtxt="+srch_txt+"&srchtyp="+valuee). And in the document.ready of the new window make the ajax call to retrieve the data with the parameter in the query string. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @ Mathieu Labrie Parent,I want to put data in other page because i want to show Google map in new page when user click search button then data coming with some address and when user click address then show map to user

Comment: @ Mathieu Labrie Parent can you tell me how to pass query string??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the new window use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://medicomall.com/andapp/?srchtxt=" + srch_txt + "&srchtyp=" + valuee,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (opt) {
        $("#LoadingImage").hide();

        //Window Settings
        var w = window.open();
        //Append Search unordered list
        $(w.document.body).html('<ul class="search"></ul>');

        $.each(opt.waleed, function (key, value) {
            //  alert( "SUCCESS:  " + value );         
            if (value == 'Medicine') {
                $(w.document.body+" .search").html("<li>" + this['med_name'] + "</li>" + "<li>" + this['med_alter'] + "</li><a>" + this['Store_Address'] + "</a><br>");
            } else if (value == 'Doctor') {
                $(w.document.body+" .search").html("<li>" + this['name'] + "</li><li>" + this['desc'] + "</li>");
            } else {
                $(w.document.body+" .search").html("<li>" + this['cl_name'] + "</li><li>" + this['cl_address'] + "</li>");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        $("#LoadingImage").hide();

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i m facing the same problem i have tried your code but the result is same when new window open it shows same white screen

Comment: @farrukh could you create a jsfiddle and add your code so I can have a look.

Comment: @farrukh I also realised that I changed the `valuee` to `value` by accident, my bad.

Comment: @ David Passmore Thanks Problem is solved i have change valuee to value