# How to show success function response on some other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-ajax

My question is- I have Index page with two forms one for hotel booking and one for train booking.the forms toggle.if hotel link clicked then hotel form opens and same for train.

Previosly, i was having same form on HotelList page and at that time, i was simply submitting form with ajax call to api controller and getting back response within onSuccess function callback.I have posted entire flow here to make my ques readable http://pastebin.com/DkNDMXmJ

Now, exactly same form here on Index page and on submit button click, posted form data to same web api controllere api/Hotel/HotelList but this time, i want to show whatever i get back in response to HotelList page not on index page. I can easily show data on index page but dont know how to show data on HotelList's table.

So far, i have came to know is that make non ajax call to web api controller and then redirect in post method, so i have tried this:

```
$("#btn1Post").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('<form>' + '</form>').submit({ params: { TokenId: '$("#pageInitCounter").val()' } });
```

It should hit web api controller but where to put url here.
I have to write script function here to show data whatever i get back from web api controller to HotelList page not on Index page means after getting back data should redirect to HotelList page.
Code for HotelList page i have provided earlier.

Problem is i have searched extensively but everywhere i found post with ajax jquery. i can't see any form submission with non ajax approach and redirect the response data to some other page.

what shoulod i try here. how to post this data correctly on hotel list page from script function which is entirely on Index page.

Is it possible on client side or Is it possible only on Server side page redirection technique. Is it possible only in controller method to post response to some other page with redirection.
Please guide me.

Comment: Remove `window.location.href = url;` - that's redirecting to another page (making all your ajax code which is updating the current page pointless)

Comment: i dont want to update current page instead i want to update div table of specified url means after btn click, page url should change and table on that page should be updated with response @StephenMuecke

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405708/how-to-show-ajax-response-on-new-page i am trying for something like this @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then you need to post you data and redirect in the POST method. Using ajax is pointless (the whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page)

Comment: is it possible to send response data on some new page table not on same page table @freedomn-m

Comment: can u tell me via some code syntax how is it possible. i have tried new page opens but i cant see any table data there ?? i have tried this `$("#btn1Post").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); var url = '@Url.Action("HotelList", "Home")'; window.location.href = url; $.post( { url: "/api/Hotel/HotelList", type: "Post", dataType: "json", data: // data, success: function (data) { var result = JSON.parse(data);` @freedomn-m

Comment: i tried this as u said but still not getting data in table(table is on url page not on page from where am posting form) `$("#btn1Post").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); var url = '@Url.Action("HotelList", "Home")'; window.location.href = url; $.post( { url: "/api/Hotel/HotelList", type: "Post", dataType: "json", data: // data, success: function (data) { var result = JSON.parse(data);` @StephenMuecke

Comment: @neo, You cannot use ajax. So stop trying to. Ajax calls stay on the same page. If you want to redirect somewhere else, the submit your form, and redirect in the POST method.

Comment: i am explaining in simple lang, first page only form with submit button now submit button clicked->form data gone to api controller-> api controler return response-> want to post that response on second page div, table if possible change my above code to non ajax so that i could understand better @freedomn-m

Comment: `$("#btn1Post").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('<form>' + '</form>').submit({
                    params: { TokenId: '$("#pageInitCounter").val()' }
                });` this is posting data to web api controller but how to return back data from controller without ajax @StephenMuecke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114600/discussion-between-neo-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this part of the code

```
  var table = $('#tableId');
       var rows = "<tr><td>" + hotelname + "</td>"; 
        rows += "<tr><td>" + address + "</td></tr>";
           table.append(rows);
```

before closing table in

```
 <div id="divResult5"></div>
    <table id="myTable">
         <tr></tr>
       <tbody id="tableId"></tbody>
        </table>
```

Please let me know if anything works.

Comment: it will never work @anjali here only solution would be to post data to new page and grab id of the table of that page and i am searching how to do it

Comment: oh ok. Sorry..@neo